# Using Ubuntu for a NAS server

Tags: server, bittorrent, nas

I would like to setup a NAS server in my house something like [this](http://lifehacker.com/5919558/turn-an-old-computer-into-a-networked-backup-streaming-or-torrenting-machine-with-ubuntu).

Basically for storing and sharing files in my network, download torrents, keep a bitcoin node (just for me, to have my bitcoins in my machine) and to automate a couple of things. I do not want FreeNAS or something like that because I want to do whatever I want with my server and no just things supported out-of-the-box.

For sure, I will use an old PC for this. I don't have it yet but, I thinking on 2gb memory, 1.2/1.6ghz.

I have a couple of questions:

- Should I use Ubuntu Desktop or Server? Does the desktop version
  consume more resources?
- If I use the server version, is it possible download bitorrent with
  command lines?
- Is Ubuntu appropriate for this? Or, should I look for a lighter
  distro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this based on my experience using Ubuntu as my home server. I did not use an old PC, though - I built my own custom system in a little box, but it has desktop-class specs (2.8GHz and 8GB RAM). I use it primarily as a Plex Media Server, and it also does some file management, occasional torrents, downloads podcasts, has local time and DNS servers, VPN, and for occasional virtualization experiments. [I built my system with Plex and virtualization in mind, which is why I put all those resources in it. I'm sure I wouldn't need all those resources for the other things I do.]

**Question 1: Should I use Ubuntu Desktop or Server? Does the desktop version consume more resources?**

Yes, the desktop version will consume more resources, but if you use something like lxde or xfce, it probably will not impact performance in a way that would noticeably affect the kind of use you are describing. If you feel confident in your command line skills, you can use the server version, but like this article suggests, the desktop version contains or can install anything in the server version, is easier to setup, and offers a GUI if you ever need one.

If you start from Ubuntu Desktop, lxde or xfce is simple to install from the software center or the repos. If you start from Ubuntu Server, it is always possible to install a GUI after the fact, but I've never tried it.

**Question 2: If I use the server version, is it possible download bitorrent with command lines?**

I don't know about the default bittorrent client (Transmission). But [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org/), which I use, features a command line interface and a web-based UI as optional features. I use its web UI, which is excellent, and which I can access from other computers and devices on my network or outside my network via VPN. Deluge is available from the Ubuntu Software Center or from the repos.

**Question 3: Is Ubuntu appropriate for this? Or, should I look for a lighter distro?**

Ubuntu Server is minimal in terms of system requirements. Ubuntu Desktop might get a little cramped if you use Unity, especially if you're not going to be looking at it a lot. (My home server runs Ubuntu Desktop 12.04, but with a lot more RAM than you're talking about, so your mileage may vary.)

If I were trying this, I would probably start by trying Ubuntu Desktop (just because I'm still more comfortable with a GUI to fall back on if needed), and if that doesn't perform well, I'd try again with Server edition.

Comment: My setup is old laptop w/ Core 2 Duo, 1GB running Ubuntu Server from a 16gb pendrive. Running Plex Media Server, SickBeard, Sabnzbd, deluge (web), Samba, a bitcoin node (only at nights, it kills my hd and generates high temperature what produces noise) and a couple of scheduled tasks (auto-backups, system snapshots, etc). It is incredible that I can watch a movie with that. Thank you for sharing your experiene.

Comment: For those that have the same questions that I had, use the server version. It is not difficult and you learn much more.